# Set Electron App as Default Web Browser

Tags: browser, electron

I am developing an Electron App that needs to function like a Web Browser.  The application needs to be able to be set as a default Web Browser on a Windows 10 machine.  How would you go about doing this?

Comment: You don't, electron is not meant to be used as web browser, there are multiple drawbacks performance wise, it is highly vulnerable if you don't know what you're doing + yet unkown breaches. Just use Chrome or if its too much google for you use Chromium.

Comment: I only need to do it for testing purposes; it won't be used in production.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to set the File & Protocol associations. Look into [electron-builder](https://www.electron.build/), specifically, `fileAssociations` in their [documentation](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration).

For files, you would want to support (one or all of) these extensions:

- `htm`
- `html`
- `shtml`
- `webp`
- `xht`
- `xhtml`

For protocols, you would want to support (one or all of) these:

- `FTP`
- `HTTP`
- `HTTPS`

Comment: I am currently using electron-builder.  I added that to my build in package.json (see [here](https://jsonblob.com/cd8b901e-5791-11e8-ba95-b7c36bf8aa35)), but that doesn't seem to work.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure. If you open "Default Apps" (`ms-settings:defaultapps`), does your App show up there to be assigned as the default? Does the App have a signed certificate (I'm guessing that might not have anything to do with it, but was just curious)?

Comment: No, it doesn't show up as an option to be default.  It does not currently have a certificate, but as you said, I don't think that has to do with it.

Comment: However, I can set it as a default app for opening file types, e.g. html/htm, etc.  It just does not appear as a usable Web Browser.

Comment: @dav I am working in something similar so I took a look to your json as a reference, and I noticed that ext and description were inside an object, inside an array - looks weird - and also that protocols are outside fileAssociations (the docs says that protocols come inside fileAssociations, and, if well the fileAssociations is said to be an array, I have seen other examples that shows it being just an object). 

Might be the reason it is not working?